# MYSQL Stored procedure for concatenating code

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contain some fields(id,code,name,...), when I want to insert new record the code field should be like (ABC-001) and next record should be like (ABC-002) and so on.
I want to write a MYSQL procedure for this but I don't know how, any body has any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: Should `id` field strictly correspond with number in `code` field? (i.e. When id= 5 then code must be ABC-005 ?)

Comment: You can use trigger or simply use LAST_INSERT_ID() in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

First User Insert Query like:

```
Insert Into YourTable Values(..,'ABC',...);
```

Now write trigger after update which set Code value in expected format:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerNmae AFTER INSERT ON YourTable
FOR EACH ROW
Begin

  UPDATE YourTable
     SET code = concat(code,'-',LPAD(NEW.id,3,'0'));
   WHERE id = New.id ;

END;
```